# HtmlDataTable in Richfaces 4

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I'm getting the following message after upgrading all my jars to Richfaces 4.

```
The import org.richfaces.component.html.HtmlDataTable cannot be resolved
```

For this import:

```
import org.richfaces.component.html.HtmlDataTable;
```

Would I be correct in saying I need to use the following instead now?

```
import org.richfaces.component.UIDataTable;
```

And if so, will replacing the following code:

```
HTMLDataTable table = (HtmlDataTable) component;
```

with the following work exactly as before?:

```
UIDataTable table = (UIDataTable) component;
```

Appreciate any help, I can't find anything on this using Google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changed the code to use:

```
UIDataTable table = (UIDataTable) component;
```

This worked :)